# Write nested network in file (e.g. gml, graphml or nnf) using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, cytoscape, graphml

I'm currently trying to build a block model using the python package `networkx`. I found that the function `networkx.quotient_graph` can be used for this job:

```
g_block = nx.quotient_graph(G=g, partition=node_list, relabel=True)
```

In the next step, I want to export the generated block graph "g_block" to a file to import it afterwards in a visualization tool that supports for example graphml-files.

```
nx.write_graphml(g_block, 'test_block.graphml')
```

However, this leads to the error:

> {KeyError}class 'networkx.classes.graphviews.SubDiGraph'

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Currently `networkx` (version 2.2) doesn't support nested graphs in a way you can easily export and visualize. Consider using *[graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/)*  for handling your nested graph and export it to a [dot](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) format.

For working with a `networkx` version of the graph, you can transform the `pygraphviz` to a `networkx` graph and vise versa by keeping a 'graph' property for nodes (which is semantically a subgraph), similarly to the result of `quotient_graph`.

Here is an example of transforming a small `networkx` graph to `pygraphviz` with subgraphs, and exporting it as a `dot` file:

```
import networkx as nx
import pygraphviz as pgv

G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(6, 0.5, directed=False)
node_list = [set([0, 1, 2, 3]), set([4, 5])]
pgv_G = pgv.AGraph(directed=True)
pgv_G.add_edges_from(G.edges())
for i, sub_graph in enumerate(node_list):
    pgv_G.add_subgraph(sub_graph, name=str(i))

print(pgv_G)
pgv_G.write("test_pgv.dot")
```

Note that `netwrokx` also allows writing and reading 'dot' format (see [example](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/pygraphviz/write_dotfile.html)), however since there is no built-in support for nested graphs it's not too helpful for this purpose.

---

The reason you can't write the `quotient_graph` is twofold:

1. In a `quotient_graph` each node has a 'graph' property, which is a `SubDiGraph` (or a `SubGraph`, if the original graph is undirected). A `SubDiGraph` is a `ReadOnlyGraph` which means it is not possible to write it using the standard `networkx.readwrite` utils.
2. Even if we convert the `SubDiGraph` to a `DiGraph`, not every graph file format allows to encode a 'graph' property. For example, graphml format supports primitive properties such as booleans, integers etc. Read more [here](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/graphml-format/).

One solution that works is to solve the first issue by overriding the 'graph' property with a `DiGraph` copy of the original `SubDiGraph`. The second issue can be simply solved by using another file format (e.g., pickle format can work). Read about all supported formats [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html).

Following is a working example:

```
g_block = nx.quotient_graph(G=G, partition=node_list, relabel=True)

def subdigraph_to_digraph(subdigraph):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(subdigraph.nodes())
    G.add_edges_from(subdigraph.edges())
    return G

for node in g_block:
    g_block.nodes[node]['graph'] = subdigraph_to_digraph(g_block.nodes[node]['graph'])

nx.write_gpickle(g_block, "test_block.pickle")
```

This allows to write and load the nested graph for using with `netwrokx`, **however** for the purpose of using the exported file in a visualization tool this is not too helpful.